# Правильная организация процесса разработки ПО

Tags: документация, работа, agile

Во многих учебниках, описывающих подходы к разработке программных продуктов, говорится о том, "что" нужно делать и примерно в какой последовательности это нужно делать. Это, конечно же, полезно знать, и можно даже считать себя крутым "архитектором"/тимлидом/etc, пока не столкнешься с проблемой лоб в лоб на практике.

И когда происходит это столкновение, оказывается, что способов того "как" осуществить тот или иной этап разработки много и все они со своими подводными камнями.

Взять к примеру написание ТЗ для разработчиков. Возникают вопросы: насколько оно должно быть детальным? Как разбить ТЗ по секциям так, чтобы не заниматься его написанием слишком долго (да и нужно ли это вообще)? Где грань между тем, что должен разжевать разработчикам тимлид и тем, что они должны осмыслить сами?

Далее, допустим, ТЗ было сформировано на достаточном для всех уровне абстракции. Возникает вопрос: как начать с разработчиками планировать действия - то, как они будут делать что-то? Способов, опять же, достаточно много - например, взять один раздел ТЗ и начинать писать по нему техническое описание решения, что по сути и будет первыми набросками архитектуры одной из многих частей конечного продукта. Но у такого подхода много очевидных проблем, перечисление которых излишне.

Прямо говоря, вопрос заключается в том, как организовать процесс разработки в команде, не рискуя "съесть" все ресурсы и всё время на планирование, так и не приступив к сути - к разработке?

Comment: Ваш вопрос похож на спагетти и только вызывает дополнительные вопросы. Может переформулируете?

Comment: Это "спагетти" внесено умышленно, чтобы подвести читателя к вопросу в конце

Comment: Ваш ответ в вопросе: практика и опыт. Ни в одной книжке и ни в одном курсе не знают какие у вас реальные проекты и не смогут дать универсальной инструкции. ТЗ важно, но вы можете не описывать работу всех функций и не составлять для них интерфейсы, вы можете своим Senior сказать, что конкретно от них нужно, а они далее сами разобьют большие задачи под более мелкие для своей группы.

Answer (score 1):

Это не простой вопрос, сходите на обучение по управлению разработкой.
Если кратко - ТЗ пишем от бизнес задачи, структурируя по разделам (без технической информации)

Архитектура приложения - отдельный этап и делается либо архитектором либо (обычно) самим разработчиками тоже верхнего уровня или вообще делается в процессе разработки (зависит от сложности и размера проект).

Планирование делаете в крупную клетку - вместе с разрабами при старте, по каким-то разделам в ТЗ (дополняя ТЗ).

Затем каждый спринт в начале спринта - формулируете задачи с запасом на этот и следующий спринт.

Уровень детализации ТЗ, описания, самих задач - зависит от уровня разрбаботчиков, вашего уровня - договаривайтесь с командой об этом уровне.

Проработанное ТЗ на уровне бизнесового запроса - очень важно, для правильно понимания процесса - все интерфейсы лучше сделать дизайнером - и включить в ТЗ, как и сложные расчеты (сделать примеры в гугл таблицах)

Если проект сложный - архитектуру делает отдельный опытный человек в разработке, разработчики способы сами понять сложность проекта.

Оценка общего срока хорошо понятна разработчикам - когда они видят интерфейсы проекта, сложные расчеты. Но можете со своим опытом смело умножать на 3-4. Потом поймете на сколько умножать.

А планирование задач по сринтам - это самое простое - можно у самих разрабом спросить что они хотят сделать за неделю и формализовать в задачи с результатом.

Если в проекте много интерфейсов - лучше подключить на это отдельного верстальщика (если фронта нет в команде) - чтобы ускорить процесс разработки.